Выполнение функций по расписанию
Всем привет!
Вопрос в следующем. Есть три функции:
def func1():
   #do something
   return value1
def func2():
   #do something
   return value2
def func3():
   #do something
   return value3

далее есть функция main, в которой результат этих трех функций записывается в словарь. примерно вот так:
def main():
   #do something
   my_dict = {
    'key1': func1(),
    'key2': func2(),
    'key3': func3()
}
   #do something with my_dict 

Как можно настроить выполнение функции main так, чтобы функция func1() и func2() запускались каждые 10 секунд, а функция func3() - каждые 20 секунд? Выполнение функции main должно быть по сути бесконечным, пока приложение активно. Функции 1, 2 и 3 при каждой итерации возвращают разные значения. Из функции main, соответственно, после каждой итерации должно возвращаться соответствующее
Мне кажется, что можно что-то через модуль threading придумать, но что-то никак в голову не приходит решение =(

Если верно уловил вашу мысль, то действительно можем попробовать решить вашу задачу через модуль threading.
Пример кода:
import threading
import time
import random
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict

def func1():
    return random.randint(1, 10)

def func2():
    return random.randint(20, 30)

def func3():
    return random.randint(40, 50)

def run_func(thread_data, func, interval = 10):
    stop_event, lock, my_dict = unpack_thread_data(thread_data)
    name = func.__name__
    
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        result = func()
        with lock:
            my_dict[name].append(result)
        stop_event.wait(interval)
    print(f"Поток {name} остановился!")

def print_dict(thread_data):
    stop_event, lock, my_dict = unpack_thread_data(thread_data)
   
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        with lock:
            print(my_dict)
        stop_event.wait(2)
    print("Поток print_dict остановился!")
    
def unpack_thread_data(thread_data):
    return thread_data.stop_event, thread_data.lock, thread_data.my_dict
    
def create_thread_data():
    ThreadData = namedtuple('ThreadData', ['my_dict', 'lock', 'stop_event'])
    
    return ThreadData(
        defaultdict(list),
        threading.Lock(),
        threading.Event()
    )

def start_threads(thread_data):
    threads = [
        threading.Thread(target=run_func, args=(thread_data, func1)),
        threading.Thread(target=run_func, args=(thread_data, func2)),
        threading.Thread(target=run_func, args=(thread_data, func3, 20)),
        threading.Thread(target=print_dict, args=(thread_data,))
    ]
    
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    
    return threads    

def stop_threads(threads, stop_event):
    stop_event.set()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    print("Все потоки остановились.")

def main():
    thread_data = create_thread_data()
    threads = start_threads(thread_data)
    
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Процесс прерван. Ожидаем завершение потоков...")
    finally:
        stop_threads(threads, thread_data.stop_event)
        input("Enter для выхода из программы!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Вывод:
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6], 'func2': [27], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6], 'func2': [27], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6], 'func2': [27], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6], 'func2': [27], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6], 'func2': [27], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4], 'func2': [27, 21], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4], 'func2': [27, 21], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4], 'func2': [27, 21], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4], 'func2': [27, 21], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4], 'func2': [27, 21], 'func3': [42]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4, 8], 'func2': [27, 21, 21], 'func3': [42, 48]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4, 8], 'func2': [27, 21, 21], 'func3': [42, 48]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4, 8], 'func2': [27, 21, 21], 'func3': [42, 48]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4, 8], 'func2': [27, 21, 21], 'func3': [42, 48]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4, 8], 'func2': [27, 21, 21], 'func3': [42, 48]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4, 8, 7], 'func2': [27, 21, 21, 23], 'func3': [42, 48]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'func1': [6, 4, 8, 7], 'func2': [27, 21, 21, 23], 'func3': [42, 48]})
Процесс прерван. Ожидаем завершение потоков...
Поток print_dict остановился!
Поток func1 остановился!
Поток func3 остановился!
Поток func2 остановился!
Все потоки остановились.
Enter для выхода из программы!

P.S. Ctrl+C - для принудительной остановки программы.

уважаемый @amgarak, это именно то, что мне было нужно! искал золото, нашел алмаз! чуток подпилил напильником функцию print_dict, чтобы из my_dict можно было получать только не пустые значения, и сразу же чистить их. я восхищен! спасибо Вам огромное! у меня остался только один вопрос: весь мой скрипт в итоге соберется в exe-файл через pyinstaller с onefile и noconsole, и будет крутиться на сервере. вручную, соответственно, потоками не смогу управлять, только начать и убить фоновый процесс exe'шника в ОС сервера. не будет проблем с потоками в таком случае? корректно ли они остановятся?

@cold_reader думаю вам лучше создать отдельный вопрос, где вы сможете более подробней изложить что за ос на сервере, какие вычисления вы хотите делать в своих функциях и т.д. Что бы более предметно можно было вам ответить или уточнить подробности.

Можно сделать с помощью генераторов.
import time


def func1():
   #do something
   return value1
def func2():
   #do something
   return value2
def func3():
   #do something
   return value3


def main():
    count = 2

    while True:
        time.sleep(10)

        my_dict = {
            'key1': func1(),
            'key2': func2(),
        }

        if count % 2 == 0:
            my_dict['key3'] = func3()

        count += 1

        yield my_dict  # (1)


n = main()  # (2)

print(next(n))  # (3)
print(next(n))


yield - ключевое слово по работе напоминающее return но не прерывающее функции. Оно делает функцию генератором.

Записываем объект генератора в n

Далее, сколько нужно получаем след. значение с помощью next.


